# Pronouncing long decimal numbers

Tags: числительные, математика

I know that there isn't a very simple way to pronounce decimals in Russian. They translate literally as "X wholes, X tenths/hundredths/etc.", where X is feminine.

As such, *0.1* becomes ноль целых, одна десятая; *0.01* becomes ноль целых, одна сотая — if I'm not mistaken, that is.

But, what if I wanted to pronounce, colloquially, a number like *0.333333333333(...)*, that is to say a number with an infinite amount of decimal places?

In that case, could I say the numeral's components individually? Like "ноль точка три три три три (...)"?

Comment: You'd say *ноль целых, три в периоде*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think there's any set rule, but as a native speaker, I can advise the following options: First you have to know that in Russian the decimal separator is the comma `,` (pronounced *запятáя*, colloquially *и*), not the point `.`:

> 0,333... – *ноль и три, три, три [и так далее]...*
>
> 0,333... – *ноль, запятая, три, три, три [и так далее]...*

More scientifically:

> 0,333... = 0,(3) – *ноль целых и три в периоде*
>
> 0,133... = 0,1(3) – *ноль, запятая, один и три в периоде*

Comment: The answers on the page http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1501/decimal-declension say decimal digits are usually pronounced in groups of two or three at a time, but 0,33333333... would not be ноль и тридцать три тридцать три и так далее?

Comment: Well, this variant is acceptable, I think. As I said, there is no set rules regarding this.